# how do I populate html form fields from a dynamic form dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to figure out a way to fill html form fields based on the selection of a dynamic form dropdown menu.

I have been looking around and trying to tweek what I have found. So far I am up to filling one of my form fields. But have no gone off piste trying to fill all three, leaving the radio empty when I want it to pick up the 0 value on all my dummy entries and select enable (0)

```
    <option value="<?= $row['ENABLED2'] . " - " . $row['ID2'] . " - " . $row['SOLDTO2'] ?>"> ..</option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ddlModel").on("change", function() {
                var GetValue = $("#ddlModel").val();

                const GetValueArray = GetValue.split(" - ");

                var GetValueSold = GetValueArray[2];
                var GetValueID = GetValueArray[1];
                var GetValueEn = GetValueArray[0];

                $("#SOLDTO2").val(GetValueSold);
                $("#ID2").val(GetValueID);
                $("#ENABLED2").val(GetValueEn);

            });
        });
    </script>
    ...
    <FORM id='addClient' action='process/process-addclient.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' id='ID2' name='ID2' maxlength='4' placeholder='Four Digit Sage Code' style='display:inline'>
    <textarea id='SOLDTO2' name='SOLDTO2' placeholder='Client Name and Address - 6 Lines Max'></textarea>
    <input type="radio" name='ENABLED2' id='enable' value='0'> <label for='enable'>Enable Client</label>    
    <input type="radio" name='ENABLED2' id='disable' value='1'> <label for='disable'>Disable Client</label>
```

In writing this out I have answered some of my own questions but I cant figure out how to get the last column (radio) to populate.

I am new to JS/JQ

Answer (score 1):

The way to populate the radio field is by using the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ddlModel").on("change", function() {
            var GetValue = $("#ddlModel").val();

            const GetValueArray = GetValue.split(" - ");

            var GetValueSold = GetValueArray[2];
            var GetValueID = GetValueArray[1];
            var GetValueEn = GetValueArray[0];

            $("#SOLDTO2").val(GetValueSold);
            $("#ID2").val(GetValueID);
            $("#ENABLED2").val(GetValueEn);

            //Check radio field based on value of GetValueEn
            if (GetValueEn == 0) {
                $("#enable").prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $("#disable").prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect and a face pal 'of course its an if statement' moment :) I have tried to up vote but my rep is 0 but it did say it 'was recorded' Thank you again.

Comment: I am glad the code worked, it is fine if you were not able to upvote.